# System.Drawing Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I'm currently using AForge dll to render the video on the picture box for the live view. I do have a video frame function to whether WriteFrame or Screenshot the current picturebox frame as a JPG.

But i met a problem when sometime the program will prompt out an error of Parameter is not valid or Object is been used elsewhere. I did try to find solution to solve it and i pretty sure i did dispose on the image and the clone image, but the problem still exist.

Could you assist me on what i had done wrong with my program?

```
void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //your code using bmp object
            if (D1Pic.BackColor == Color.Green)
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                if (livePreview.Image != null)
                {
                    //Dispose the resources
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { livePreview.Image.Dispose(); }));
                }
                livePreview.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                imgclone = (Image)livePreview.Image.Clone();
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
            }
            else
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                if (livePreview.Image != null)
                {
                    //Dispose the resources
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { livePreview.Image.Dispose(); }));
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { video.Dispose(); }));
                }
                livePreview.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                imgclone = (Image)livePreview.Image.Clone();
            }
            video.Dispose();
            livePreview.Refresh();
```

Here are the stack trace error :

```
{"Parameter is not valid."}
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

UPDATED CODE :

```
 var newFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                {
                    if (livePreview.Image != null)
                    {
                        livePreview.Image.Dispose();
                    }
                    livePreview.Image = newFrame;
                }));
                imgclone = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

                //Write frame into video
                if (D1Pic.BackColor == Color.Green)
                {
                    video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                    FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
                }
```

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: @JeremyThompson livePreview.Refresh()

Comment: Try `livePreview.Invalidate()` instead.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I did try with the livePreview,Invalidate(). After sometime the program still throw me the "Parameter is not valid" exception.

Comment: Post the *entire* exception details, and indicate which line throws it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Okay, I'm awaiting the program to throw the error now. Will post It here Shortly

Comment: @Blorgbeard I had posted the error. But it does not show me which line that the error occur instead of just prompt from "Application.Run(new Main());"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `livePreview.Image.Dispose()` in the UI thread, but you're not setting `livePreview.Image` to null afterwards.

So between the time that you dispose `livePreview.Image` and the time that you assign a new image to it, `livePreview.Image` points to a disposed object.

So I think occasionally your picturebox tries to draw itself during this time, and fails when it attempts to access its (disposed) Image property.

The solution would be:

```
if (livePreview.Image != null)
{
    //Dispose the resources
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { 
        livePreview.Image.Dispose(); 
        livePreview.Image = null;
    }));
}
```

Or even better, assign the new image in the same step:

```
var newFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { 
    if (livePreview.Image != null)
    {
        livePreview.Image.Dispose(); 
    }
    livePreview.Image = newFrame;
}));
```

In general, you need to understand what's happening with your various Bitmap objects. Anything that keeps a reference to a Bitmap that has been disposed will be a problem.

Comment: Is that same for the video also?
I mean the FileWriter for the video recording

Comment: I don't see a problem with that part, it's all happening on the same thread as far as I can see.

Comment: Please see my update code, i had make changes on my code. Is that okay with the code?

Comment: I'm using imgclone on saving part. Do you want to see that? I will dispose it after the imgClone.Save function. Will that lead to parameter is not valid? Currently I'm running the program and let see whether the problem will occur or not

Comment: It shouldn't cause an ObjectDisposedException, since you are not disposing it in another thread, so (hopefully) you're not accessing it after it has been disposed. Is `video` also used elsewhere? I don't see it declared in the code you posted, so I assume it's a member-level field, but you are disposing it in the code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112738/discussion-between-marcus-and-blorgbeard).